# Change format of images (from PS to EPS) using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, eps, postscript

I have a question from experts in using Ghostscript. I am new in using this software. How can I change the format of an image from PS to EPS using Ghostscript?

Comment: Have you done any internet searching for this question? It appears this is a basic function of the application and similar questions here on SuperUser contain the answer as well: https://superuser.com/questions/182368/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps-on-windows/189052#189052

Comment: @music2myear That question asks about converting ".PDF to .eps". That'snot what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a very recent version of Ghostscript. It so, run this command:

```
gs -o output-%00d.eps -sDEVICE=eps2write input.ps
```

For more ancient versions, use

```
gs -o output-%00d.eps -sDEVICE=epswrite input.ps
```

Note that EPS by design is and may only be single-page document format.

So if your single file *input.ps* consists of multiple pages, your output will consist of multiple EPS files ("images") which are named *output-001.eps*, *output-002.eps*, etc.